# Global variable disappear out of the function

Tags: php, mysql, function, global

I have a little problem and I can't find the reason..
I have this easy function that should check if the user/pass are correct and i would like to save all the infos about the user from $row *object* into $userdata **global** *object*

```
function check_credentials($username, $password) {
    global $userdata;       
        $password = md5($password);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 0,1")or die(mysql_error());


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        if(($row->password == $password) && ($row->username == $username) && ($row->ver == 1)) {

            $userdata = clone $row;
            return true;
        }
        else break;
    }
    }
    unset($_SESSION['logged_as']);
    return false;
}
```

Do you have any idea of why, out of the function, the global variable disappear ? because it should be **global**

Comment: how did you define the $userdata variable before?

Comment: @Broatcast i did not. $userdata is declared as global at the beginning and it is "filled" just before the return true

Comment: you can not define it with the global state at start of the function, you need to define this variable outside of the function before... the global statement only give you read/write access to the outside defined variable in you function ... this is your problem

Comment: @Broatcast Can you give me more infos? how to? I don't want to use $GLOBALS["name"]

Comment: just define your variable before, for example at your first using point before you first time calling it in a function like `$userdata = array();` for example. then its empty in your function you get then read/write access for this $var with the global state. you can still use it outside and load it to other functions

Comment: I tried, but still nothing sadly. I declared $userdata = null out of the function, then declared the function as posted. But after the function, still nothing.

Comment: this mean, the global statement in a function it self, only give you read/write access to a variable that is defined before. so you can read or change this variable, if you dont have defined it before its not working cause the global command not define this variable, it only allow to access an exist variable.

Comment: No problem, I forgot to re-use it as global in another function for page loading. Your solution was correct. Thank you so much!

Comment: the code where did you define it will be executed before? make a test define this variable like `$userdata = 'test';` then add after the global command in the function a `var_dump($userdata);` if you defined it correctly you will see the output string test if not you defined it not at the correct place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Broatcast said, the global function must have been declared out of the function before.

```
$var = null;
function name() {
global $var
}

// use $var as global
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function simply returns boolean true, not the modified variable.
Change

```
            $userdata = clone $row;
            return true;
```

to

```
        $userdata = clone $row;
        return $userdata;
```

Comment: I can't. The function itself must return only true or false if user/pass are correct. The other effect is that out of the function $userdata is still available.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using using a global variable, just return the $userdata:

```
if(($row->password == $password) && ($row->username == $username) && ($row->ver == 1)) {
return $row;
}
```

Then capture the row when you call the function

```
$userdata = check_credentials($username, $password);
```

Comment: I can't. The function itself must return only true or false if user/pass are correct. The other effect is that out of the function $userdata is still available.

Comment: an non-empty array will evaluate as true in a boolean context.

Comment: Also, if you store $userdata to a global, the $userdata is still available after the function returns. As a matter of fact, it is available *globally*.

Comment: did you even read the question? the problem is that $userdata should be available globally because it is global, but it doesn't.

as is it now, if I try to var_dump($userdata) out of the function, i get "NULL"